# With each docker-compose up, my flask app sends +1 too many emails

Tags: postgresql, flask, docker-compose, flask-sqlalchemy

I have been working on a flask website app for learning/practice. Its a website that shows a list of gpu models and their prices all webscraped from a list of urls. The user signs in and the enters a desired-price for a gpu form and clicks subscribe and a checksubs script runs once a day to compare desired-price vs price and well send email to buy. Its a postgres db with sqlalchemy models/tables that are: gpu , users, price, subscriptions. I got the app to a working state I was happy with and then moved on to try format it for a docker-compose deployment where the flask-app, webscrape, postgres, and emailsubs are all set as services defined in the docker-compose.yml.

My issue started when I added a docker volume into the docker-compose.yml. I wanted data persistence for the postgres db between docker-compose up and down. Now each time I docker-compose up, it sends +1 more emails for each subscription. ex lets say there's one sub in the db that is a match for desired_price >= price, if this is my second time running a docker-compose up it will send 2x the emails for the sub. And if I docker-compose down then up it will then send 3x the emails for the sub. Also want to point out that I have removed any multithreading from the code as it was the first thing I thought to try for fix.

The issue does not occur without a docker volume. Also if I add a new sub on lets say the third docker-compose up, it will send 3x emails for the new sub as well. This also was not an issue when I ran the code on a local postgres db. At first I thought my flask app was initializing a 'new' db with each 'flask run' so I added logic to check if tables already exist in db before db.create_all():

```
max_retries = 10  # You can adjust this number as needed
    retries = 0

    while retries < max_retries:
        try:
            with app.app_context():
                # Directly query the information schema to check for table existence
                query = text("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'gpu')")
                result = db.session.execute(query)
                table_exists = result.scalar()

                if not table_exists:
                    print("Database tables not found. Initializing...")
                    db.create_all()
                else:
                    print("Database tables already exist.")

            break  # Break out of the loop if database setup succeeds
        except OperationalError:
            print(f"Database connection failed. Retrying in 5 seconds ({retries}/{max_retries})")
            time.sleep(5)
            retries += 1
    else:
        print("Failed to establish database connection after multiple retries. Exiting.")
        return None  # Return None to indicate failure
```

...but no luck although it does recognize the tables existing after first fresh flask run.

Here's the docker-compose.yml (with redacts ofc):"

```
version: '3'
services:
  flask-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URI=postgresql://...:...@postgres/...
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -h postgres -U dbuser"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
   
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ...
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ...
      POSTGRES_DB: ...
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    
    
  webscraper:
    build:
      context: .  
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.webscraper  # Dockerfile for the webscraper service
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - flask-app  
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -h postgres -U dbuser"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
 

  checksubs:
    build:
      context: .  
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.checksubs  # Dockerfile for the checksubs service
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - flask-app 
      - webscraper  
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -h postgres -U dbuser"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

volumes:
  postgres-data:
    driver: local
```

"
but I am pretty sure this is correct where only the postgres service gets a volume. Lastly I suppose the issue could be with my email sending code. But it worked fine with the localhost postgres:

```
def main():
    # Load database URI from config.json
    config_path = 'config.json'  # Adjust the path to reach the config.json file
    env = os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV', 'development')

    with open(config_path, 'r') as config_file:
        config = json.load(config_file)

    db_uri = config[env]['DATABASE_URI']

    # Database connection setup
    engine = create_engine(db_uri)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    # Establish SMTP connection
    smt = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    smt.ehlo()
    smt.starttls()
    email = os.environ.get('SENDER_EMAIL')
    password = os.environ.get('SENDER_PASSWORD')
    smt.login(email, password)

    # Get subscription data using SQLAlchemy query
    subscriptions = (
        session.query(
            Subscriptions.user_id,
            Subscriptions.gpu_id,
            Price.price,
            Users.email,
            GPU.model,
            GPU.url
        )
        .join(GPU, Subscriptions.gpu_id == GPU.id)
        .join(Price, GPU.id == Price.gpu_id)
        .join(Users, Subscriptions.user_id == Users.id)
        .filter(Subscriptions.desired_price >= Price.price)
        .all()
    )

    for subscription in subscriptions:
        user_id, gpu_id, price, user_email, gpu_model, gpu_url = subscription

        # Create email
        subject = "Price notification"
        message = f"Hey, the price of {gpu_model} has dropped to ${price:.2f}. Buy it!\nLink: {gpu_url}"

        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = 'price-watcher@gmail.com'
        msg['To'] = user_email
        msg['Subject'] = Header(subject, 'utf-8')
        msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain', 'utf-8'))

        # Print the email details for server log
        print(f"Sending email to: {user_email}")

        # Send email
        smt.sendmail('price-watcher@gmail.com', user_email, msg.as_string())

    # Clean up
    smt.quit()
    session.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

... maybe/hoping you can see something I am not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The issue was my query above. Because the price table would add/Insert new rows for every webscrape, there would be a new set of Price rows for every webscrape and with my flawed query above it would make a subscription for every case of a price for the particular gpu_id. New fixed query only uses the max date value from the price table:

````
# Get subscription data using SQLAlchemy query
        latest_price_subquery = (
            session.query(Price.gpu_id, func.max(Price.date).label("latest_date"))
            .group_by(Price.gpu_id)
            .subquery()
        )

        subscriptions = (
            session.query(
                Subscriptions.user_id,
                Subscriptions.gpu_id,
                Price.price,
                Users.email,
                GPU.model,
                GPU.url
            )
            .join(GPU, Subscriptions.gpu_id == GPU.id)
            .join(Price, GPU.id == Price.gpu_id)
            .join(Users, Subscriptions.user_id == Users.id)
            .join(latest_price_subquery, Price.gpu_id == latest_price_subquery.c.gpu_id)
            .filter(Subscriptions.desired_price >= Price.price)
            .filter(Price.date == latest_price_subquery.c.latest_date)
            .all()
        )```
````